# Как привязать скрипт к лицензии?

Tags: защита, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Как привязать скрипт к лицензии? И настроить проверку ее на удаленном сервере. Также интересует вопрос, как создать систему автоматических обновлений.

Comment: Ща придут опенсорсеры и начнется холивар со сжиганием ведьм ^_^
А вообще тож интересно, реально ли вообще защиту пхп скрипту поставить. Вообще вспоминая, как рашн хакерз сломали старфорс под чашку кофе и 2 бутерброда, у меня в этом большие сомнения)

Comment: Как вариант зашифровать скрипт, но спасет только от ламеров.

Comment: А как перенести функционал скрипта к нам на сервер?

Answer (score 4):

Скрипт необходимо зашифровать с помощью утилиты Zend Safeguard Suite. В таком виде из скрипта никто не сможет вырезать вашу собственную проверку лицензий. Если эту утилиту приобрести то можно будет делать из неё лицензии, привязывая их, наприрмер, к домену, кол-ву установленных копий или ip адресу сервера. Перед шифрацией можно провести обфускацию кода, это еще жёстче. Конечно, кто - то скажет что дезендер всё расшифрует, это не так, последствия дезендера ужасные, код нечитаемый и в 99% случаев неработающий.

Система автоматических обновлений это отдельная огромнейшая тема, я с ней слава богу не сталкивался, поэтому ничего не подскажу. =)

Comment: Обновление - довольно банально. запрос "Дайте последнюю версию", запрос "/download/script_version_#LAST_VERSION#.php", если  есть - заменяем. Ну это так, на коленке) 

Расскажите про зенд, на среднем дешевом хостинге проблемы будут? Модуль какой-то нужен или он где-то там внутри пхп? Я вообще не в теме, а курить англицкие доки не хочу :-[

Comment: Про Зенд.
Для того чтобы зашифрованные файлы на сервере работали должен быть Zend Optimizer (если версии не совпадут об этом будет уведомление в браузер с рекомендацией что делать). Очень часто он уже предустановлен на площадку, реже нет (но его можно установить самостоятельно, например, по ssh пересобрав php). Некоторые компании(я знаю только одну такую :) ) не дают его устнавливать, мотивируя это тем что он создает дополнительную нагрузку на сервер, до 15%, я её не заметил. На коммерческих площадках с ним проблем не будет. На совсем бюджетных, сказать сложно, я никогда с ними не имел дел.

Comment: Про систему обновлений.
Не всё так просто, дать то он даст но нужно, обновить структуру БД, структуру исполняемых файлов, подклчюить какие то новые библиотеки и т.д. - это АДЪ. А если проект еще не типовой и там что то дописывалось, то как сделать так чтобы при обновлении это не пострадало и всё потом работало... вобщем АДЪ.

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт является обычным текстовым файлом, поэтому прямая защита скрипта мало реальна, взломщик отыщет то место в скрипте, где происходит проверка лицензии и удалит ее. Чтобы избежать этого надо вынести существенную неотъемлемую часть функционала из скрипта либо в компилируемый код, либо на свой собственный сервер и уже там отслеживать лицензию. Саму проверку обычно делают на основе активации, которая так или иначе привязывается к акту купли-продажи лицензии.

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги, а что вы скажете вот про это? Интересно ваше мнение. Имеется [скриптик](http://www.tex-spassk.ru/tmp/test5.php) и [файлик лицензии](http://www.tex-spassk.ru/tmp/file.lic), который генерится к домену. На моем [домене скрипт работает](http://www.tex-spassk.ru/tmp/test5.php), а на другом домене без лицензии не работает. Если кому интересно, то можете попробовать "расковырять" код. Здесь привожу только кусок кода, а целиком скрипт можно [скачать здесь](http://www.tex-spassk.ru/tmp/test5.php.txt).

```
<? eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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'))); ?>
```

Comment: ЭТО расковыривается, вычищается лицензия, потом сковыривается обратно.
Я так как-то хакерский скрипт расковырял, который доступ ко всему сайту давал, а владельцу отсылал данные для входа.
Вот эту самую отсылку я вычистил, остальное запихал обратно. Получился неплохой инструмент для редактирования сайта хоть с мобильника.

Comment: @knes +1

@Damon замените eval на echo, вот и весь "взлом"

Comment: да, я в курсе про этот фокус ... а дальше?

Comment: дальше я думаю, что надо искать if :)

Comment: Ну это ж совсем от нубов) Умение читать код и все. Насколько я понял, адекватом будет zend + необратимая обфускация пару раз + привязка к файлу лицензии, где домен раз нацать зашифрован с солью+ша512+мд5) Тогда это, по крайней мере, сделает расшифровку сложным. Меня например пару раз остановило фразой "Да ну нааааа" ближе к утру)